# How to reduce space of tooltip box in highchart?

Tags: highcharts

I'm creating new variablepie highchart js. In that graph how to reduce space(height) of tooltip box. I need to reduce top and bottom space inside the tooltip box.

URL: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/variable-radius-pie

```
   tooltip: {

           headerFormat: '',
            pointFormat: ' <b>COMPANY</b><br/>' +
                'Match Percent: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>' +
                'Score Weight: <b>{point.z}</b><br/>',
                valueSuffix: ' %',
                useHTML: true,
                outside: true,
                style: {
                        padding: 0
                },
                followPointer:true
        },
```

Comment: Unfortunatly I don't that possible to reduce only the top and the bottom [documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.padding)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `padding` directly in a `tooltip` configuration object:

```
tooltip: {
    padding: 0,
    ...
}
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/eom8tqns/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.padding

Comment: He asked for top and bottom not all sides.

Comment: Thankyou once again. I need to solve few more quires.
1) Is possible to positioning tooltip for each section.
2) Inside the tooltip box i need to align value "float-right". Is it possible?
3) Is possible to change height of tooltip box and cursor pointer?

Comment: Hi @Anish Sharma, I see that you have already created a different thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56179841/positioning-each-tooltip-in-highchart

Answer (score 0):

But the main thing is, it will only support numbers not px values