# Positioning each tooltip in highchart

Tags: charts, highcharts

I'm using Highchart library for creating variablepie chart.

I have a few questions about using that library:

1. Is it possible to position the tooltip for each section?
2. Inside the tooltip box, I need to align value "float-right". Is it possible? 3. Is it possible to change height of tooltip box and cursor pointer?

URL: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/eom8tqns/

```
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '',
    padding: 0,
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> <b> 
    {point.name}</b><br/>' +
        'Area (square km): <b>{point.y}</b><br/>' +
        'Population density (people per square km): <b>{point.z}</b><br/>'
},
```

Comment: What do you mean saying "positioning tooltip for each section"?

Comment: Thanks for your time. [link](https://ibb.co/Jq9ZNtR) . Please see the image. I need the tooltip on hover the each label need to show like this.Now the space between chart and tooltip is large.

Comment: You can change the default position of a tooltip using `tooltip.positioner` callback function. Check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/68xbq5va/1/, API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.positioner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To align values right and change the height of the tooltip set appropriate CSS styles:

```
.highcharts-tooltip {
  text-align: right;
}

.highcharts-tooltip > span {
  height: 100px;
}
```

The cursor can be set in series properties:

```
series: [{
  cursor: 'pointer',
  data: data
}]
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v2txyp6h/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.cursor

Comment: Thankyou. I have one more query. Is it possible only the value ("<b>{point.z}</b>") b tag text-align:right?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You can make it simply with css. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8rgstq17/1/